# Why is O'Sullivan always sitting on the left side?

Tags: snooker

In every snooker game I have watched O'Sullivan has always been sitting on the left side. Why? How is this decided in the first place?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, and I can't find a source to back this up at the moment, but I think it is customary that the higher seeded player is seated on the yellow pocket side. Though I'm unsure how this is applied in the earlier stages of the World Championship at the Crucible, for example, where both players are sat in the same corner because of the two table arrangement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at the sessions from the 17 days of the Snooker World Championship in 2020 to see if the theory that the higher seeded player is seated by the yellow pocket side. This seems to be the case and the highest seeded players score will also be shown on the left side on the screen as well.

In a two table setup the highest ranking player will still sit on the left side but in the same corner. I have also noticed that the lowest seeded player will be announced to the table before the other.